# schedule image using python

Tags: python, png

How can I generate an image of a schedule similar to this using python? [image]

If possible, point me to a simple library that does the job. I tried matplotlib, but since my knowledge in matplotlib is quite limited, I was stuck. I also want the text boxes to support text wrapping if text were to exceed the width of the box.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-gui-calendar-using-tkinter/#